# How to query the array of objects in Tableau Desktop?

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

How to query the array of objects and display it in Tableau. If I drag and drop table array columns are not listing, the rest of the columns are displaying.
While using custom SQL it gives an error as the Unknown column.
Could you please help me with how to fetch array objects from the table in Tableau desktop?
Note: We are using the MongoDB database.

An error occurred while communicating with MongoDB BI Connector
Bad Request: The data source does not contain the expected data.
Error Code: 9CE6AC3B
[MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.4]Unknown column 'details.Tasks' in 'field list'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8lb2.png)

Comment: hi. were you able to find any solution? I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array or Object will be available in the data source tab in the left pane. Under the main table, it will be available as a Virtual table.

In the below image document_action_plan is a virtual table created which is an object in the document_action collection.

[image]